# useState array and async scope lookup

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, scope

Consider the state of a component that is dependent on two asynchronous calls. One is an initial call, the other a recurring one.
Both change an array controlled by `useState`. The array is appended to by spreading the old array into a literal.

The issue is when both calls resolve they set the same state, but the spread with the old array is a scope lookup from the time `useEffect` was called. So one of the calls always 'overwrites' the other.

Here is some simplified code:

```
const Component = () => {
  const location = useLocation()

  const [numbers, setNumbers] = useState([1,2,3])

  // say this returns [4,5,6]
  useEffect(()=>{
    fetchOnce().then(newNumbers => setNumbers([...numbers, newNumbers]))
  }, [])

  // say this returns [7,8,9]
  useEffect(()=>{
    fetchMultiple().then(newNumbers => setNumbers([...numbers, newNumbers]))
  }, [location])
}
```

The final result is either [1,2,3,4,5,6] or [1,2,3,7,8,9].

How to change it so the state is set correctly?
I should be [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] or [1,2,3,7,8,9,4,5,6].

Comment: Shouldn't the final result be either `[1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]` or `[1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 2, 3, 4]`? You don't have 8 or 9 anywhere

Comment: @CertainPerformance You're absolutely right, I'll change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the callback form of `setNumbers` instead:

```
const Component = () => {
  const location = useLocation()

  const [numbers, setNumbers] = useState([1,2,3])

  // say this returns [2,3,4]
  useEffect(()=>{
    fetchOnce().then(newNumbers => setNumbers(numbers =>[...numbers, ...newNumbers]));
  }, [])

  // say this returns [5,6,7]
  useEffect(()=>{
    fetchMultiple().then(newNumbers => setNumbers(numbers => [...numbers, ...newNumbers]))
  }, [location])
}
```

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;
const fetchOnce = () => Promise.resolve([2, 3, 4]);
const fetchMultiple = () => Promise.resolve([5, 6, 7]);
console.error = () => void 0; // suppress key warning, not sure what OP wants for keys

const Component = () => {
  const [numbers, setNumbers] = useState([1,2,3])
  useEffect(()=>{
    fetchOnce().then(newNumbers => setNumbers(numbers =>[...numbers, ...newNumbers]));
  }, [])
  useEffect(()=>{
    fetchMultiple().then(newNumbers => setNumbers(numbers => [...numbers, ...newNumbers]))
  }, [location])
  return (
    <div>
      {numbers.map(number => <div>{number}</div>)}
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Component />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class="react"></div>
```